# How to check only the first radio in vuejs v-for?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How to put inline if in checked property on input in the vuejs?

this is my code

```
<div v-for="(element,index) in elements" :key="element.id" class="col">
    <input type="radio" name="test[]" :value="element.id" :checked="if (index==0):'checked'">
</div>
```

Igot error message : avoid using JavaScript keyword as property name: "if"
  Raw expression: :checked="if (index==0) 'checked'"

Comment: You need a ternary expression: `:checked = "index === 0? true: false"`. You can't really write much code inline, you could also pass a function which could receive the index, something like: `:checked="someVar"` @change="changeChecked(index)"` the. function `changeChecked` would receive the index and toggle the `someVar` property.

Comment: @Michael, got it, thank you

Comment: Sure, feel free to upvote my comment :-)

Comment: @Michael, yes I wanna do but unfortunately I'm not allowed to upvote, I think because I'm new!

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do:

```
<div v-for="(element,index) in elements" :key="element.id" class="col">
    <input type="radio" name="test[]" :value="element.id" :checked="index===0 ? true: false">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this will be enough:

```
<input
   type="radio"
   :checked="index === 0"
/>
```